# The output from calling New-AzureRmVm is inaccessible until it is returned to caller

Tags: azure, powershell

When calling New-AzureRMVM, the Output includes an object that represents the VM that is created, but the object is inaccessible until I'm outside the function.

In the code snippet below, while inside the function Create-VM, the output ($newVM.Name)  is $null. But if I return $newVM to the caller, then $V.Name contains a value.

```bsh
# PSVersion                      5.1.17763.503                                                                                                                                                 

Function Create-VM 
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$vmName

        # and some others ... 
    )

    # Snipped
    try 
    {
        $newVM =  New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroup # ... 
        Write-Host "newVM.IsSuccessStatusCode = $($newVM.IsSuccessStatusCode)" 
        Write-Host "newVM.Name  = $($newVM.Name)" 
        return $newVM
    }
    catch 
    {
        # Snipped
    }

}

$vmName ="testvm1"
$V = Create-VM  -vmName $vmName # .... 
if ($V) 
{
    Write-Host $V.GetType() # why does this return System.Object[]?
    Write-Host "V.IsSuccessStatusCode = $($V.IsSuccessStatusCode)" 
    Write-Host "V.Name  = $($V.Name)"  # why does this return a value??? 
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
WARNING: New-AzureRmVM: A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming breaking change release. The StorageAccountType property
for a DataDisk will return Standard_LRS and Premium_LRS
newVM.IsSuccessStatusCode = True
newVM.Name  =
System.Object[]
V.IsSuccessStatusCode = True
V.Name  = testvm1
```

Stepping through this code in a debugger, we can see that $newVM is a single object of type  "PSAzureOperationResponse" object when inside the Create-VM function, but when it is returned to the caller, it becomes an System.Object[] array of two objects :

- $V[0] is type "PSAzureOperationResponse"
- $V[1] is type "PSVirtualMachine"

That is why $newVM.Name returns $null but $V.Name returns the name property of the VM object ("testvm1")

Can someone explain how this works? There must be some weird output binding going on.

PS. A new VM is indeed correctly created!

Comment: Try to Write-Host $newVM.Name outside the try{}catch{} in your function.

Comment: The result is the same - it is $null.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute the script provided above (with minor changes) on my machine running the same version of Powershell 5.1.17763.503 and AzureRM version 6.13.1, and was able to access the newVM object fine within the Create-VM function and post return as well. Here is the script and the output:

```
# PSVersion                      5.1.17763.503    
# AzureRM                        6.13.1                                                                                                                                        

Function Create-VM 
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$vmName

        # and some others ... 
    )

    # Snipped
    try 
    {
        $newVM =  New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName # ... 
        Write-Host "`nnewVM.StatusCode = $($newVM.StatusCode)" # StatusCode is the property
        Write-Host "newVM.Name = $($newVM.Name)" 
        Write-Host $newVM.GetType()
        return $newVM
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Host "in the catch block"
    }

}

$vmName ="testvm1"
$V = Create-VM -vmName $vmName # .... 
if ($V) 
{
    Write-Host "`nOut of Create-VM"
    Write-Host $V.GetType()
    Write-Host "V.StatusCode = $($V.StatusCode)" 
    Write-Host "V.Name  = $($V.Name)"
}
```

Output:

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: testvm0

newVM.StatusCode = 0
newVM.Name = testvm0
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine

Out of Create-VM
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine
V.StatusCode = 0
V.Name  = testvm0
```

Can you try upgrading to the latest version of [AzureRM](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/6.13.1) and check if it helps? If not, you might add wait/sleep period for a few seconds.